# MAMP PRO relative url

Tags: url, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP PRO and the relative url's stay relative. This means that for example href="app.css" is aded to www.domain.nl/app.css. This is ok but when you are on the page www.domain.nl/ad/overview.html then the link becomes www.domain.nl/ad/app.css instead-off www.domain.nl/app.css. On the production server the url's work correct.

Any one an idee if this is an setting in MAMP PRO?

Answer (score 0):

set a href this way:

```
<link href="/app.css" ...>
```

Comment: I understand that this works. Only I'm wondering if it can be fixed by changing a setting in MAMP (apache) as on the production server <link href="app.css" ...> also works fine. Then I don't need to change al the code in my project.